# Get bounding box for everything that can be seen in OpenGl

Tags: opengl, volume, bounding-box

How to get a bounding box on everything visible onscreen in pure OpenGL? I want the X, Y, and Z for all 8 points of the bounding box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL doesn't define a fixed 'box' volume that you see on the screen. In a sense, the application defines these boundaries - [which do not, in general, form a rectangular prism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum) - using transforms and projections. The nearest thing to such a 'bounding box' is the *normalized device coordinate space* or 3d viewport *after* projection.

A [bounding box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume) that encloses all your geometry in *world coordinate space* is something you must determine from your data, and has nothing to do with the GL pipeline.

---

To recover the points in world coordinate space (WCS) that map to the corners of the viewport, you need to understand how matrix transforms and homogeneous coordinates work.

The 'front' or 'near' plane in normalized device coordinate space (NDCS) after projection (division by W), is: `Z/W = -1`. NDCS is a *left-handed* coordinate space.

This corresponds to the *hyperplane*: `Z = - W`, in clipping coordinate space, so any (homogeneous) point of the form: `(x, y, -z, z)` will project to: `(x/z, y/z, -1, 1)`.

The canonical view volume that is mapped to the 3D viewport, is defined by:
`-1 <= X/W <= 1, -1 <= Y/W <= 1, -1 <= Z/W <= 1`, bounded by the (6) hyperplanes:

> X ± W = 0, Y ± W = 0, Z ± W = 0 (the homogeneous *clipping* planes)

So the above can be extended to find the (homogeneous) coordinates corresponding to the 'corners' of the view volume which correspond to the 3d viewport. Consider the top-right corner of the viewport, on the 'near' plane. It corresponds to: `(1, 1, -1, 1)`, though any point of the form: `(W, W, -W, W)` would project to the same 3D (NDCS) point.

Given some matrix: `[M]` transforms a point `P` (in WCS) to yield `Q = (1, 1, -1, 1)`, it's then simply a matter of using the inverse (matrix) transform: `P = inv[M] * Q`

The same idea can be applied to each 'corner'. It's also extremely useful for picking - a picking ray runs from the 'eye' to the WCS inverse projection of `(x, y, -1, 1)`.

---

**Note:** This is more detail than I intended to go into, and probably beyond the OP's requirements, but I see questions about *picking* come up a lot.

Comment: Picking using raycasting requires rather lenghty explanation, which could probably be better written as tutorial article. I've always solved it by hashing values in color, rendering offscreen and reading said color from the mouse position. Works like a charm.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, sounds very heavy handed for a geometric problem! Like the old GL_SELECT mode rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need OpenGL for that? It's you drawing things, so just run a function through all of your data. Take the projection into account and discard results outside the view volume; the checks are pretty straightforward, especially when using orthographic projection.

Answer (score 0):

I think in OpenGL, what is on screen is a [frustum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frustum), not a box.

Comment: Depends. It's a frustum when using perspective projection, or a box when using orthographic projection. And I didn't even start on vertex shaders yet, which can map pretty much everything to everything.